# Select Rows From First Table, For Same Column Values in Second Table

Tags: sql

My requirement is as follows: for each `Deal Id`, I want to check its corresponding records in the `Deal Interest` table, and if any one for the row contains `Y` for the `UserModified` column, I do not want to select that `Deal Id`.

So at the end output should contain these Deal Ids:

- 1001 - NO - As One of the record in Deal Interest Table is Y
- 1002 - YES - As all entries are N
- 1003 - YES - As all entries are N

Table structures are as follows:

`Deal` table:

```
+-------+------+---------+
|Deal_ID|Status|InputMode|
+-------+------+---------+
|1001   |V     |C        |
+-------+------+---------+
|1002   |V     |C        |
+-------+------+---------+
|1003   |V     |C        |
+-------+------+---------+
```

Deal Interest table:

```
+------+------------+-----------+
|ARIDNR|UserModified|PaymentDate|
+------+------------+-----------+
|1001  |N           |2021-10-12 |
+------+------------+-----------+
|1001  |N           |2021-11-12 |
+------+------------+-----------+
|1001  |Y           |2021-12-13 |
+------+------------+-----------+
|1001  |N           |2022-01-12 |
+------+------------+-----------+
|1002  |N           |2021-11-24 |
+------+------------+-----------+
|1002  |N           |2021-12-23 |
+------+------------+-----------+
|1003  |N           |2021-11-14 |
+------+------------+-----------+
|1003  |N           |2022-01-11 |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you. Tag properly and just tag the technology you are using/asking about.

Comment: I, somehow, doubt that you use MySQL, MS SQL Server and Oracle at the same time. Which database do you really use?

Comment: As for your question, what is it? You don't ask anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to know all ID's that have no row in `DealInterestTable` with value `Y` in column `UserModified` ?
If that is correct, then this query might help you

```
select d.Deal_ID
from   Deal d
where  not exists (select 1 from DealInterestTable it 
                   where it.ARIDNR = d.Deal_ID 
                   and it.UserModfied = 'Y')
```